# Is there a significant GC performance gain by re using float arrays in Java?

Tags: java

I am developing an Android game in Java, and the garbage collector regularly kicks in and causes a lag spike.

After looking at my object allocation, a big portion of what gets recycled is a float[]. I create a new float[] every frame for multiple objects.

Does it make sense to re use a float[] or is the performance impact of it insignificant (especially compared to objects).

```
public float[] rectangleToVerts(float x, float y, float width, float height) 
    float[] verts = new float[8];

    verts[0] = x - width / 2;
    verts[1] = y + height / 2;
    verts[2] = x + width / 2;
    verts[3] = y + height / 2;
    verts[4] = x + width / 2;
    verts[5] = y - height / 2;
    verts[6] = x - width / 2;
    verts[7] = y - height / 2;

    return verts;
}

public void tick(){
    shape.setVertices(rectangleToVerts(x, y, 5, 5);
}
```

### VERSUS

```
public float[] rectangleToVerts(float x, float y, float width, float 
    height, float[] verts) 

    verts[0] = x - width / 2;
    verts[1] = y + height / 2;
    verts[2] = x + width / 2;
    verts[3] = y + height / 2;
    verts[4] = x + width / 2;
    verts[5] = y - height / 2;
    verts[6] = x - width / 2;
    verts[7] = y - height / 2;

    return verts;
}

private float[8] verts;

public void tick(){
    shape.setVertices(rectangleToVerts(x, y, 5, 5, verts);
}
```

Comment: An array is an object, so offhand there wouldn't be any difference compared to using  some different object.  For your alternatives, though, I wouldn't have a problem with a shape having `verts` stored rather than assigning/recalculating/garbage each time.  If you have LOTS AND LOTS of shapes, there could be an increase in memory overhead, so worth being aware of weak memory references in that case if it proves appropriate.

Comment: @racraman There are on average around 15 shape objects (never exceeding 20) in the level at once. Do you think this optimization would help to prevent GC from causing momentary lag spikes or will there be no difference in performance?

Comment: Reusing objects, including arrays, is likely to reduce GC churn, especially on Android.

Comment: It's not so much "at once", but how many have been created/destroyed between GC runs or spikes.   If you're only creating 15-20, then I'd be surprised if that has a big impact on the GC;  on the other hand, 15-20 per frame @ 25 fps with spikes 5 seconds, that's a couple of thousand.  Still, try the different alternatives and see.  For 15-20 at once, though, certainly not worth worrying about the weak references I mentioned.

Comment: @LouisWasserman totally agree - both for `verts`, and also (or especially) the shapes themselves if possible.

Comment: As others have implied, the only way is to try it and see. And if you're shooting for a mass market, it's best to try on as many different devices as you can. Outguessing GC is tough. Hanging onto buffers can reduce pressure on ephemeral collection, but creating long-lived objects can also create other problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly how much more efficient your code will be in the second example, but it is certainly more efficient. Each array is itself an object, and the fewer new references you create, the less often the Garbage Collector will run. Since you said that a large portion of what gets recycled is float[] types, this seems like a likely candidate. If you're working in Android Studio 3.0 or higher, you can use the [Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler://) to see how memory is allocated by your program and determine if this is in fact the source of your slowdown.

As a side note, you're also calculating the values of each vertex twice. (For instance, verts[0] and verts[6] are both being set to x - width / 2.) A quick and easy optimization might look like this:

```
public float[] rectangleToVerts(float x, float y, float width, float height, float[] verts) 
{
    verts[0] = x - width / 2;
    verts[6] = verts[0];        

    verts[1] = y + height / 2;
    verts[3] = verts[1];

    verts[2] = x + width / 2;
    verts[4] = verts[2];

    verts[5] = y - height / 2;
    verts[7] = verts[5];

    return verts;
}
```

Hope this helps!